# How to auto update a form textfield from a uploaded .csv file using JSP?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, csv

I've created a JSP file for creating a form.

I'm trying to auto update or print data automatically into a text field in a form by uploading a .csv file using input type=file tag and then calculate the total price of items from the .csv file using JSP. That is I've to print the total price calculated from the .csv file onto the text field of the form.

Below is the JSP file.

Say the .csv file contains only 1 column containing prices of different items.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/bootstrap.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-area">  
            <form role="form" method="post" action="../AddDistributorDetail">             <br style="clear:both">
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Distributor Registration</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Distributor Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Contact No #1:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact1" name="contact1" placeholder="Contact No1" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Contact No #2:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact2" name="contact2" placeholder="Contact No2" required>
         </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label">Address #1:</label>
                         <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="address1" placeholder="First Address" maxlength="200" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label">Address #1:</label>
                         <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="address2" placeholder="Second Address" maxlength="200" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label">City:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Pincode:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" placeholder="Pincode" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Zone:</label>
          <div class="radio">
             <label><input type="radio" name="zone">East</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
             <label><input type="radio" name="zone">South</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
             <label><input type="radio" name="zone">West</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
             <label><input type="radio" name="zone">North</label>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">STB Limit:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stblimit" name="stblimit" placeholder="Set Top Box Limit" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Credit Limit:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="climit" name="climit" placeholder="Max Credit Limit" required>
         </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label">Upload STB Inventory</label>
          <input type="file" class=" file form-control" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Total Cost Of Inventory</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tcost" name="tcost" placeholder="Total Cost Of Inventory" required>
         </div>
               <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Form</button>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Even though I understood as how to read a csv file in JSP, I searched the internet but didn't find any logic as how to upload the file and calculate the total price in real time(i.e in the same JSP page and before clicking the submit button) and print it the text field in the form.

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the file using ajax form submit. After uploading, in the server side just read the csv and writes the result back in the response. After receiving the result you can manipulate the dom element.

The easier way is to use the javascript "FileReader" api, which will be supported in most browser

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var readFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("myTextarea").value =reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      };
</script>
<body>
  <input type='file' onchange='readFile(event)'><br>
<textarea id='myTextarea'></textarea>

</body>
```

Js fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/gtxfye8m/

I've tested in chrome, edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pojo class and declare all the fields which are present in the file and read the fields from your csv file and then set it into the respective objects that can be mapped to your jsp fields.

Comment: For eg:
Class details
{
String distributorName;
public String getDistributionName(){
return this.distributorName;
}
public void setDistributionName(String abc){
 this.distributorName=abc;
}

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't think I can access the csv file before clicking the submit button. Only after printing the total sum in to the text field I have to hit submit.